# Unity3D Vertex colored shader (colored in editor , black in build)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to user a very simple shader in order to avoid creating 1 material per color (using vertex color method). The problem comes when i see that it's ok in editor, but when i build in android or standalone(windows) , all colors seems black.

Screenshots:
Editor
[image]
Build
[image]

Shader

```
Shader "Alpha/VertexLit Colored" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }

    SubShader {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert alpha
        struct Input {
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };
        fixed4 _Color;

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            o.Albedo = IN.color.rgb ;
            o.Alpha = 1;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

Part of code where i set colors:

```
Mesh mesh = minoGameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Color[] colors = new Color[mesh.vertexCount];
for (int i=0;i<mesh.colors.Length;i++)
{
    colors[i] = mino.color;
}
mesh.colors = colors;
```

Any idea of how can i solve the problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The shader is loaded? You assign it dynamically? Is it in the resources folder?

Comment: I resolve my problem using unity3d vertex colored shader. I have tried what you said anyway (resources folder). Thanks for reading.